# How to create a OnCellDblClick for Delphi's TDBGrid

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

I'm a newbie when it comes to creating new events to components... and I noticed that `TDBGrid` has a `OnCellClick`, but sadly it doesnt have an **OnCellDblClick** event and it bothers me a lot the fact that if I double click anywhere in my grid the selected row will be used...

So, I wanted to create the OnCellDblClick event, but as I've said earlier, I don't know how to do it.

I noticed that a lot of people want this same event, but I can't find the answerd to it.

Is it possible to know if the double click was on a record, if it was, then do all the stuff I want with it?

Comment: You can ask with the `GetMessagePos` function for the position when the `OnDblClick` triggers and from that (after proper coordinate calculation) determine double clicked cell by the `MouseCoord` method. Or, you might e.g. override `MouseDown` method and handle double click in the way DB grid does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `DblClick` together with the `MouseDown` event of the DBGrid
**But this will only work if the `Options.dgRowSelect` is false**

for example

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    FEmptySpace : boolean;
 ...

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  // in my test I only get here when clicked on empty part of the dbgrid
  FEmptySpace := TRUE;
end;

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FEmptySpace then
    showmessage('clicked in the middle of nowhere...')
  else
    showmessage(DBGrid1.Fields[DBGrid1.SelectedField.Index].AsString);

  FEmptySpace := FALSE;
end;
```

I have not tested this in all situations

In my test

- `Options.Editing := false`
- `Options.dgRowSelect := false`
- `Readonly := true`